# how to get the selected value of dropdown column in datainit function using jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid with loadonce set to true and 2 dropdowns which are cascaded. I want to load second dropdown based on the selection in first dropdown using dataurl. However the line 
var v = $(elem).val();

within datainit of the first column always returns null and hence the second dropdown is always loaded with the default url. Please suggest me an answer as I have been working around this for a couple of days now. 
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Both dropdown columns should have in colModel the following:

```
         edittype:"select"
```